# Merging contents of columns using apply or other vectorized approach

Tags: r, apply

I have a data.frame that is almost entirely blanks, but each row has one value. How can I use a vectorized or other r-vernacular approach to merge the contents of each row into a single vector?

sample data:

```
raw_data  <- structure(
    list(
        col1 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
        col2 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
        col3 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
        col4 = c("", "", "", "Millburn - Union", ""),
        col5 = c("", "", "Cranston (aka Garden City Center)", "",""),
        col6 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
        col7 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
        col8 = c("", "", "", "", "Colorado Blvd"), 
        col9 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
        col10 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
        col11 = c("Palo Alto",  "Castro (aka Market St)", "", "", "")
    ),
    .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11"),
    row.names = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L),
    class = "data.frame"
)
```

This is what I tried but it fails, as it returns a 2-dimensional matrix instead of the desired vector:

```
raw_data$test <-  apply(raw_data, MAR=1, FUN=paste0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition about `apply` is right.  You just need to pass the `collapse` argument to `paste`:

```
 apply( raw_data, 1, paste0, collapse = "" )
                                  5                                   4                                   3 
                        "Palo Alto"            "Castro (aka Market St)" "Cranston (aka Garden City Center)" 
                                  2                                   1 
                 "Millburn - Union"                     "Colorado Blvd"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this very simply with a single index operation:

```
raw_data[raw_data!='']
```

Demo:

```
R> raw_data[raw_data!=''];
[1] "Millburn - Union"                  "Cranston (aka Garden City Center)" "Colorado Blvd"                     "Palo Alto"                         "Castro (aka Market St)"
```

If you care about the vector order being top-to-bottom (as opposed to left-to-right then top-to-bottom, which is what the above operation does), you can transpose the input data.frame:

```
R> t(raw_data)[t(raw_data)!=''];
[1] "Palo Alto"                         "Castro (aka Market St)"            "Cranston (aka Garden City Center)" "Millburn - Union"                  "Colorado Blvd"
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example, there is only one element per row that is not `''`.   Here, is another way to use `paste` with `do.call`

```
do.call(paste, c(raw_data, sep=''))
#[1] "Palo Alto"                         "Castro (aka Market St)"           
#[3] "Cranston (aka Garden City Center)" "Millburn - Union"                 
#[5] "Colorado Blvd"
```

Suppose, if there are multiple elements per row in 'raw_data' that are not `''`, in that case, it may be better to use `sep=';' or`,`.

```
raw_data[1,1] <- 'Millburn'
raw_data[1,3] <- 'Something'
gsub('^;+|;+$|(;);+', '\\1', do.call(paste, c(raw_data, sep=';')))
#[1] "Millburn;Something;Palo Alto"      "Castro (aka Market St)"     
#[3] "Cranston (aka Garden City Center)" "Millburn - Union"           
#[5] "Colorado Blvd"
```

`apply` gets the same result as above

```
unname(apply(raw_data, 1, FUN=function(x) paste(x[x!=''],collapse=';')))
#[1] "Millburn;Something;Palo Alto"      "Castro (aka Market St)"    
#[3] "Cranston (aka Garden City Center)" "Millburn - Union"         
#[5] "Colorado Blvd"
```